# Cross-platform null handle OR ignoring a process' output

Tags: haskell, process

This seems pretty straightforward a problem: if on a Unix system I want to discard output of a process (from the `process` library), the following comment ([original Haddock link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.5.1/docs/System-Process.html#v:NoStream)) seems relevant:

> ... If you wish to ignore the child process's output you should either create a pipe and drain it manually or pass a `Handle` that writes to `/dev/null`.

And it works fine. The problem I have is that `openFile "/dev/null" WriteMode` does not work properly on Windows - it creates an actual file called `/dev/null`.

Is there some cross-platform way of getting a `Handle` that just ignores its input? Other SO questions have me thinking one of `openFile "nul" WriteMode` or `openFile "null" WriteMode` should work, but neither seem to properly ignore output (see [this line 462 of this log](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/harpocrates/haddock#L462) for an example of the former *not* working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [File paths under Windows](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html#file-paths-under-windows) in the GHC manual:

> Since GHC 8.6.1, the Haskell I/O manager automatically promotes paths
>   in the legacy format to Win32 file namespace. By default the I/O
>   manager will do two things to your paths:
>
> - replace `\` with `\\`
> - expand relative paths to absolute paths
>
> If you want
>   to opt out of all preprocessing just expliticly use namespaces in your
>   paths. Due to this change, if you need to open raw devices (e.g. COM
>   ports) you need to use the device namespace explicitly. (e.g.
>   `\\.\COM1`). GHC and Haskell programs in general no longer support
>   opening devices in the legacy format.

Thus, in GHC 8.6.1 and later, instead of using `NUL`, you now need to use `\\.\NUL`, [like `silently` had to change](https://github.com/hspec/silently/commit/2ce0d591fbd020b0df5cfeb5975c5b5159878516).

Comment: Thank you so much! Out of curiosity, do you happen to know if `\\.\NUL` also works on older GHC's?

Comment: I'm not sure, unfortunately.

Comment: No worries. For my use case I only need to support 8.8 and HEAD. I’m still a bit surprised there isn’t something in the libraries bundled with GHC that lets you get a cross-platform null handle (or at least a Maybe of one - perhaps some weird platform doesn’t have something like this).